# How to use DataSet control in a window application?

Tags: c#

I have used Dataset class in programs, but as a new learner I wonder how these Data control can be used. I am starting with DataSet control, but when I drop it in form a dialog box opens. Can somebody recommend a link having screen shots, with some words to read before.

Thanks in advance.  :)

Answer (score 1):

you can check out the MSDN Library first. as it will contain every bits n bytes of .net framework. +
you are talking about "Typed Dataset".

from MSDN :

> A typed dataset is a dataset that is first derived from the base
>   DataSet class and then uses information in an XML Schema file (an .xsd
>   file) to generate a new class. Information from the schema (tables,
>   columns, and so on) is generated and compiled into this new dataset
>   class as a set of first-class objects and properties.

1. [Dataset Desription](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bw9ksd6%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)
2. [Wroking with Dataset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bw9ksd6.aspx)
3. [Typed Dataset - step by step tutorial](http://www.mini.pw.edu.pl/~mossakow/materials/presentations/adonet.3.5/typed_datasets/index.html)
4. [Codeproject : typed dataset with  widnows forms](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19735/DataGridView-with-Detail-Edit-Form-VS-2005)